# Were these other people Chronicoms?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

We know that Enoch is a Chronicom, which is to say a sort of alien temporal observer.

When Enoch and his agents came and kidnapped

> Coulson’s team,

for the purpose of sending them where they wanted; were these other agents also Chronicoms? I’m inclined to think they must have been (would Enoch have shared their advanced technology and goals, etc. with mere mortals), but on the other hand only one pod was mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I believe Enoch was merely posing as a human leader of the group and the rest of the team were
a Shield like advanced strike team. One agent talking about how his wife thought he was doing
something else leads me to think this. I see the Chronicom as a Watcher type race who would
likely share the same distant and cerebral attitude, not the very human attitude that the other agent displayed.
Also going with the Watcher line of thinking only one agent of the race would be dispatched per
planet or sector to observe. This is just my theory though.

Comment: The last line is seemingly disproven in recent episodes, with the introduction of Noah. While we don’t know when he came to Earth, it’s implied he’s been there for a while, along with Enoch (he makes several comments indicating that they go way back).